# AES 256 Encryption implementation in android

Tags: android, encryption

I know this question is So popular in StackOverflow that How AES 256 implemented in Android, but the main problem is No any solution gives the exact encryption and decryption of AES 256. All codes are explained through Key Length of 128 and 256 which is not correct.

```
KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        sr.setSeed(seed);
        kgen.init(256, sr); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
        SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
        byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
        return raw;
```

But I need different from this, which AES 256 implementation not as the 256 key length. Please suggest me the right solution regarding the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Is your question: "How can I make an AES-128 or AES-256 key if I have keying material that's not 128-bits or 256-bits?"

Comment: Yes David.......this is the question.

Comment: How much entropy does your keying material have? And why do you want to use AES256 over AES128?

Answer (score 3):

If the keying material you have is a password, you should use [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2). If not, it's probably sufficient just to take the SHA-256 hash of the keying material, which will be 256-bits. For a 128-bit key, just use half the hash.

Note that using keying material that is less than 100 bits is extremely inadvisable.

Answer (score 0):

AES256 *always* uses a 256 bit key. If your key material has a different length, you can use the output of a hash function, such as SHA-256 to get a 256 bit key.

But if your key material has an entropy of less then 256 bits, that obviously means that you won't get 256 bits of security. Practical security suffers once you get significantly below 128 bits of security.

If your key material is a password, use a key-derivation-function such as PBKDF2 to get the key. It's deliberately slow, in order to increase the security with relatively low entropy passwords.